# Is there a way to compare two arrays and return a new array of the common elements which have the same index?

Tags: arrays, ruby

For example

```
a = [2,3,1,1]
b = [2,7,4,2]

--> c = [2]
```

My solution was:

```
c = b.select do
    |em| b.index(em) == a.index(em)
    end
```

But if I apply it to the given example it returns

```
c = [2,2]
```

Comment: I think the question could be read a few ways. What would the desired output be?

Comment: @JakeWorth: I think they're trying to implement the ["bulls and cows" game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_Cows)

Comment: @JakeWorth I 'm looking for a method which returns an array containing the common elements between two given arrays if and only if those elements also share the same index in their respective arrays. My solution works fine for most of the cases, but problems arise when the b array contains a duplicate of the common element. In that case, the select method returns the duplicate even though that duplicate is different from the value of the a array with which it shares the index. I hope I've been comprehensive.

Comment: The question is generally well-stated, though it is not clear what return value is wanted if `a = [1,1]` and `b=[1,1]`. I would think an array of indices would probably be a more useful return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to compare arrays element-wise, `zip` would be an excellent choice here.

```
a.zip(b) # => [[2, 2], [3, 7], [1, 4], [1, 2]]

a.zip(b).select {|a1, b1| a1 == b1}.map(&:first) # [2]

# or in ruby 2.7+
a.zip(b).filter_map {|a1, b1| a1 == b1 && a1} # [2]
```

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: Just for fun, after adding a `:single_elem?` method to `Array` that tests if an array has length of exactly 1:  `a.zip(b).map(&:uniq).select(&:single_elem?).flatten`

Comment: `a.zip(b).filter_map { |a1, b1| a1 if a1 == b1 }` may read better. Alternatively, `b.each_index.filter_map {  |i| b[i] if a[i] == b[i] }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [2,3,1,1]
b = [2,7,4,2]
c = b.select do |em|
  b.index(em) == a.index(em)
end
```

`b.select do |em|` takes the first element of b (which is 2). `b.index(em)` finds the first index which contains a 2, which is the **first** one. (index 0). Since array a has a 2 on the same index, the whole block is true and the element 2 is selected. But the same story is true for the last element. Again, the b array is searched and the **first** 2 is found at index 0. Hence, that 2 is also selected.

```
a.each_with_index.to_a & b.each_with_index.to_a
```

woud give you the common element(s) and their indices.

Comment: Keep in mind that the question does not ask for the indices. While they can be easily stripped from the return value using indices is not necessarily the best approach.